# Formula for Integration (by Integration by Parts) For a Product of 3 Functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Given general formulas $u$, $v$, and $w$, what is the general formula for integration by parts to calculate $\int uvw \mathbb{d}x$?

Comment: Integration by parts and pray it works? I'd be very impressed if there were a good *general* formula.

Comment: @79037662 that's actually what I'm looking for (integration by parts), but I already know the formula for a product of two functions, I just want the formula for 3.

Comment: What is the formula for 2 functions? Just apply it twice if you have 3.

Comment: it doesn't have a general formula for integrating $uv$, how come it is possible for integrating $uvw$?

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/integration-by-parts.html

Comment: @79037662 Yeah, I know that, but I'm surprised no one actually wrote it down (the formula I mean).

Comment: I know what is integration by part @ILoveMath2, but It may not possible to find the solution.

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio I just want the generalized formula.

Comment: @ILoveMath2 Ok fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it: $$\int uvw=u(v \int w- \int v'( \int w))- \int u'(v \int w- \int v'( \int w))$$

Answer (score 1):

One general idea with products of three functions is to use the product rule in the form
$$
  (u v w)' = u' v w + u v' w + uv w'
$$
and the get partial integration in the form
$$
\int u' v w = uvw - \int u v' w - \int uv w'
$$
and then the solution of your problem could be straightforward, but tedious.

Comment: Could you please write out the formula?

Comment: This is as close to a "formula" one can get so I would mark this reply as the answer. That being said if you look closely it's just the usual integration by parts rule for $u$ and $(vw)$. There simply is no special integration by parts formula for three elements and there is no need for one! :-)

Comment: @maxmilgram There should be, as you can redo it and have the full thing, no?

Comment: What I am trying to convince you of: Not every thing needs it's own formula. Otherwise you will have to remember (or look up) to many formulas. It is better to stick to the important ones and let your brain do the adaption to the specific problem. In your case the usual integration by parts rule together with the product rule (of differentiation) will yield the result just fine.

Comment: @maxmilgram Ok thank you!